# How do I share a private video with 170 people

Tags: youtube, video

Hi I have a relatively big group (about 170 people), and we want to share videos only within this group (i.e. we do not want people outside of this 170 people group to access these videos).

Now here is the problem. I understand that we can set the video as private, then edit who can view (here we enter everyone's e-mail address). Now it's very troublesome to enter 170 people's e-mail whenever there is a new video to share. We're wondering whether there is an easy way to share the video.

As a side note, we all share the same e-mail type (e.g. "@AAA.com")

Comment: How about setting up a distribution list?

Comment: Does it have to be on YouTube?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sCKoBXqvpk

Answer (score 1):

You can set your Youtube video to "Unlisted" and get a private shareable link to send en-masse via email to your group.

This should be about the easiest way.